# Not sure how to word this, but: how do I get back to a ping?

Tags: server, ssh, ping

I have a Linux server at my work and I secure shelled into it and set a ping to a private IP address. I then closed my laptop and left the office. That ping is still running right now from that server. so when I get back into the office tomorrow, how can I find the results of that ping?

Comment: This isn't a Linux site (SE *Unix & Linux* covers linux) thus I see nothing on-topic here. If you used a multiplexor to save the session (such as `screen`), you just re-attach to it.

Comment: And if you didn't use `screen` or equivalent, then your ping would have been terminated along with your SSH session.

Comment: @DougSmythies how about an  ` &` at the end?

Comment: @Rinzwind : Yes, thanks. If I also redirect the ping output to a file, then the data is there when I log on again and I can kill the process normally. I don't know how to recover the terminal output if I didn't redirect it to a file.